# Android (API level 17) - Backup API - Backup/Restore data in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, backup, restore

I am afraid I read too much about backup of data using Android Backup API however not a clear answer about is it possible to take SQLite database file and back it up.

This I have achieved (at least there were no crashes or anything). 
My question is that is it possible to retrieve this data file (sqlite .db) file and thus restore data information for my application.

Any suggestion in this regard would be helpful

I am currently creating my backup agent as follows:

```
MCBBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper
```

Comment: Other solutions: **1** - physically copy your file. **2** - export/import to a csv file (or more, if you have more tables, you can then zip the whole file set)

Comment: Thanks - this is been a very useful